# How to use single SSL for multiple ports

Tags: unicorn, puma

I need to use a single standard SSL for multiple ports like below.

1. x.x.x.x:1111
2. x.x.x.x:2222

For the first one, I would like to use my main domain and for second once, I would use the subdomain.

Please some one help me out in this.

Thank in advance

Comment: Please try AWS ?

Comment: I am using AWS only. But I'm unable to make it. I am able to run both the apps. But getting SSL to only one app.